# UICollectionView vertical padding issue

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have implemeted this method

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

So the method invokes in any case because if I change for example with `UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 100, 0)` I can see 100 pt padding on the top of each section. But if I set zero value there is still approximately 10 [image]pt between lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set that in your flow layout

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout * flow = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];
flow.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
flow.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;
flow.minimumInterItemSpacing = 0; // space between cells in row
flow.minimumLineSpacing = 0; // space between rows

yourCollectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc]initWithFrame:someFrame collectionViewLayout:flow];
```

Or Delegate Method:

```
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0;
    // space between cells on different lines
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0;
    // space beetween cells in same row
}
```

Comment: the problem was in storyboard by some reasons the custom size of UICollectionViewCell and Cell size in UICollectionView had different values, but thank you for answer